# Insert rows for missing time measurements of a negative event

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have data from an experiment where `Subject`s rated an `Event` called `f`:

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                     Timestamp = c("00:00:00.146 - 00:00:00.889", 
                                   "00:00:01.568 - 00:00:02.183", "00:00:03.642 - 00:00:04.522", 
                                   "00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.660", "00:00:01.247 - 00:00:02.229", 
                                   "00:00:03.697 - 00:00:04.926"),
                     Starttime_ms = c(146, 1568, 3642, 0, 1247, 3697), 
                     Endtime_ms = c(889, 2183, 4522, 660, 2229, 4926), 
                     Duration = c(743, 615, 880, 660, 982, 1229), 
                     Event = c("f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What is missing are the respective measurements for those **in-between timespans** where the `Subject`s **did *not* rate the event**. That's an event too, just a negative one; let's call it `nf`. How can I insert rows for those missing timespans to obtain the **complete** record including both positive and negative events `f` and `nf` shown below?

**Expected**:

```
  Subject                   Timestamp Starttime_ms Endtime_ms Duration Event
1       A 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.146          0          146      146    nf
2       A 00:00:00.146 - 00:00:00.889          146        889      743     f
3       A 00:00:00.889 - 00:00:01.568          889       1568      679    nf
4       A 00:00:01.568 - 00:00:02.183         1568       2183      615     f
5       A 00:00:02.183 - 00:00:03.642         2183       3642     1459    nf
6       A 00:00:03.642 - 00:00:04.522         3642       4522      880     f
7       B 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.660            0        660      660     f
8       B 00:00:00.660 - 00:00:01.247          660       1247      587    nf
9       B 00:00:01.247 - 00:00:02.229         1247       2229      982     f
10      B 00:00:02.229 - 00:00:03.697         2229       3697     1468    nf
11      B 00:00:03.697 - 00:00:04.926         3697       4926     1229     f
```

I've experimented with `data.table`but since I'm not fluent with this, this attempt only brought partial success:

```
unq <- c(0, sort(unique(setDT(df)[, c(Starttime_ms, Endtime_ms)])))
df[.(unq[-length(unq)], unq[-1]), on=c("Starttime_ms", "Endtime_ms")]
```

While I'm open to any solution my preference is for a `dplyr` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `tidyverse` solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  separate(Timestamp, c("start", "end"), sep = " - ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Starttime_ms = lag(end, default = "00:00:00.000"),
         Endtime_ms = start,
         Event = "nf",
         Timestamp = paste(Starttime_ms, Endtime_ms, sep = " - "),
         across(ends_with("_ms"), ~ hms(.x) * 1000),
         Duration = Endtime_ms - Starttime_ms,
         across(where(is.period), as.numeric), .keep = "unused") %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(Starttime_ms, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  filter(Duration > 0) %>%
  ungroup()
```

###### Output

```r
# A tibble: 11 × 6
   Subject Timestamp                   Starttime_ms Endtime_ms Duration Event
   <chr>   <chr>                              <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
 1 A       00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.146            0        146      146 nf   
 2 A       00:00:00.146 - 00:00:00.889          146        889      743 f    
 3 A       00:00:00.889 - 00:00:01.568          889       1568      679 nf   
 4 A       00:00:01.568 - 00:00:02.183         1568       2183      615 f    
 5 A       00:00:02.183 - 00:00:03.642         2183       3642     1459 nf   
 6 A       00:00:03.642 - 00:00:04.522         3642       4522      880 f    
 7 B       00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.660            0        660      660 f    
 8 B       00:00:00.660 - 00:00:01.247          660       1247      587 nf   
 9 B       00:00:01.247 - 00:00:02.229         1247       2229      982 f    
10 B       00:00:02.229 - 00:00:03.697         2229       3697     1468 nf   
11 B       00:00:03.697 - 00:00:04.926         3697       4926     1229 f
```

Comment: Wow! Great job!

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. The issue is to complete the time sequence separately for each group. This is what would do:

```
library(data.table)
# create sequence of complete periods for each Subject
unq <- setDT(df)[, {
  tmp <- sort(unique(c(0, Starttime_ms, Endtime_ms)))
  list(Starttime_ms = head(tmp, -1L),
       Endtime_ms = tail(tmp, -1L))
}, by = Subject]
# join and complete missing values
fmt <- function(ms) format(as.POSIXct(ms / 1000, tz = "UTC", origin = "2000-01-01"), "%H:%M:%OS3")
df[unq, on = .(Subject, Starttime_ms, Endtime_ms)][
  is.na(Event), c("Timestamp", "Duration", "Event") := .(
    paste(fmt(Starttime_ms), fmt(Endtime_ms), sep = " - "),
    Endtime_ms - Starttime_ms, 
    "nf")][]
```

> ```
>     Subject                   Timestamp Starttime_ms Endtime_ms Duration Event
>  1:       A 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.146            0        146      146    nf
>  2:       A 00:00:00.146 - 00:00:00.889          146        889      743     f
>  3:       A 00:00:00.889 - 00:00:01.567          889       1568      679    nf
>  4:       A 00:00:01.568 - 00:00:02.183         1568       2183      615     f
>  5:       A 00:00:02.182 - 00:00:03.641         2183       3642     1459    nf
>  6:       A 00:00:03.642 - 00:00:04.522         3642       4522      880     f
>  7:       B 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.660            0        660      660     f
>  8:       B 00:00:00.659 - 00:00:01.246          660       1247      587    nf
>  9:       B 00:00:01.247 - 00:00:02.229         1247       2229      982     f
> 10:       B 00:00:02.228 - 00:00:03.697         2229       3697     1468    nf
> 11:       B 00:00:03.697 - 00:00:04.926         3697       4926     1229     f
> ```

`unq` contains all periods for each subject to join on:

```
unq
```

> ```
>     Subject Starttime_ms Endtime_ms
>  1:       A            0        146
>  2:       A          146        889
>  3:       A          889       1568
>  4:       A         1568       2183
>  5:       A         2183       3642
>  6:       A         3642       4522
>  7:       B            0        660
>  8:       B          660       1247
>  9:       B         1247       2229
> 10:       B         2229       3697
> 11:       B         3697       4926
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This one is the exactly desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Timestamp, sep = " - ") %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp1 = lag(Timestamp, default = "00:00:00.000"), .before=Timestamp) %>% 
  mutate(Starttime_ms = as.numeric(hms(Timestamp1))*1000,
         Endtime_ms = as.numeric(hms(Timestamp))*1000,
         Duration = Endtime_ms-Starttime_ms) %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp = paste(Timestamp1, Timestamp, sep = " - ")) %>% 
  left_join(df, by="Timestamp") %>% 
  mutate(Event.y = replace_na(Event.y, "nf")) %>% 
  select(1, 3:6, Event.y) %>% 
  filter(Endtime_ms.x !=0) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace(., '\\.\\w', ''))
```

```
  Subject Timestamp                   Starttime_ms Endtime_ms Duration Event
   <chr>   <chr>                              <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
 1 A       00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.146            0        146      146 nf   
 2 A       00:00:00.146 - 00:00:00.889          146        889      743 f    
 3 A       00:00:00.889 - 00:00:01.568          889       1568      679 nf   
 4 A       00:00:01.568 - 00:00:02.183         1568       2183      615 f    
 5 A       00:00:02.183 - 00:00:03.642         2183       3642     1459 nf   
 6 A       00:00:03.642 - 00:00:04.522         3642       4522      880 f    
 7 B       00:00:00.000 - 00:00:00.660            0        660      660 f    
 8 B       00:00:00.660 - 00:00:01.247          660       1247      587 nf   
 9 B       00:00:01.247 - 00:00:02.229         1247       2229      982 f    
10 B       00:00:02.229 - 00:00:03.697         2229       3697     1468 nf   
11 B       00:00:03.697 - 00:00:04.926         3697       4926     1229 f
```